# Is it possible to capture transfered file to my apache server using tcpdump

Tags: apache-2.2, networking, centos, tcpdump

I have web app installed on apache server(port 80, no ssl). This apps job is to gather some information via transferred from clients files. My  goal is to check if my clients are sending proper files. So I want to capture files transferred to my Apache and then check if data format is proper.

I starting tcpdump like this:
`tcpdump -s0  -i eth0 'port 80' -vv` but the output is not what I want.

Is it possible with tcpdump running on the same server?

Comment: I think it should be your web application the one performing validation of the files it's processing. Can you modify it to do so?

Comment: No I'm not developer of this app ... in fact I am not developer at all :) I'm admin of server on wich this app runs.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want **netcat** (**nc**), **tcpdump** is for debugging at the packet level, **nc** is for redirecting network traffic.

This is non-trivial (because of security issues) but the steps are

1. Move your webserver to another port
2. Have nc listen on port 80
3. dump incoming traffic on port 80 to a log AND redirect it to the new port your webserver is listening to

[This page has a more detailed write](http://blog.hawkhost.com/2009/12/12/using-netcat-as-an-intercepting-proxy/) up on how to do it.

Finally there are 2 versions of netcat. Make sure you have the one that lets you violate pretty much every known security rule and keep in mind only root can listen on ports lower than 1024.

Edit: tcpdump *can* do what you are looking for but it's not going to be as strait forward - it's giving you the actual packets, you sound like you just want the HTTP text. To do it with tcpdump you'll want to dump it and then open the dump file in something like wireshark.

Comment: What do you mean redirect .... because in way I understand this will redirect trnsfered files and they will never reach app ?? If my understanding is correct then this way is not acceptable.

Comment: No, you use tee to do this. Netcat takes the data, splits the stream in two and sends one to the log and the other to the http server.

Comment: OK I will check this solution THX.

Answer (score 1):

Wireshark is more convenient for such a task.
You can run cli version, `tshark` to capture network traffic to a file, then copy it to your PC, open with GUI wireshark, find needed request and export using `export objects`.

Wireshark also support `tcpdump` files, made with `-w` flag